# fadein or fadeout in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i want to fadein div on its text change, i made a small function but it is not working. it changing value but not fading it.

```
$(function(){   
    $('.jqTransformSelectWrapper').find('ul').find('a').click(function(){
        var cityVal= $('.jqTransformSelectWrapper').find('ul').find('.selected').text();
        var capCity= cityVal.toLowerCase();

        if(capCity == "first"){
            $('#flightPrice').text('1').fadeOut('slow');            
        }
    })
})
```

//html

```
<a index="1" href="#" class="selected">first</a>

<span id="flightPrice">val</span>
```

Comment: could you also post your markup please?

Comment: `var capCity= cityVal.toLowerCase();` You know those psychology experiments where they present you with conflicting stimuli to confuse you? That line is like that. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to wrap the text in a span then fade that out:

```
<div class="button"><span>TEXT!</span></div>
```

and you don't want to use `fadeOut` because that will change the size of your button as the text will disappear once `fadeOut` ends and no longer take up space.  Instead animate the opacity:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).find("span").animate({opacity:0},function(){
        $(this).text("new text")
            .animate({opacity:1});  
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Dtr6/

EDIT: Slight correction, as long as you immediately fade back in it does not seem to be an issue to use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, at least in chrome.  I would expect maybe in lesser browsers to see a slight flicker, but could be wrong.

Possibly a bit cleaner using queue to avoid callbacks:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).find("span")
        .animate({opacity:0})
        .queue(function(){
             $(this).text("new text"); 
             $(this).dequeue()
        })
        .animate({opacity:1});  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Dtr6/2